# DDP and CUDA graph in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, distributed

This is my code and I am currently running it on 4 GPUs

```
setup(rank, gpus)


dataset = RandomDataset(input_shape, 80*batch_size, rank)

dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)
data_iter = iter(dataloader)


model = model(pretrained=True).to(rank)

optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.0001)
criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

s = torch.cuda.Stream()
s.wait_stream(torch.cuda.current_stream())

with torch.cuda.stream(s):
    print("[MAKING DDP Model]")
    model = DDP(model)
    print("[MODEL CREATED]")

    for i in range(11):
        optimizer.zero_grad(set_to_none=True)
        inputs, labels = next(data_iter)
        output = model(inputs)
        loss = criterion(output, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

capture_input = torch.empty((batch_size, 3, input_shape, input_shape)).to(rank)
capture_target = torch.argmax(torch.from_numpy(np.eye(1000)[np.random.choice(1000, batch_size)]), axis=1).to(rank)


g = torch.cuda.CUDAGraph()

optimizer.zero_grad(set_to_none=True)
with torch.cuda.graph(g):
    capture_y_pred = model(capture_input)
    capture_loss = criterion(capture_y_pred, capture_target)
    capture_loss.backward()
optimizer.step()


print("RECORDED")

for i in range(20):
    inputs, label = next(data_iter)
    capture_input.copy_(inputs)
    capture_target.copy_(label)
    g.replay()
    optimizer.step()


print("DATASET DONE")
```

> RuntimeError: CUDA error: operation failed due to a previous error during capture
> CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call,so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
> For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: I ran into similar issues with DDP training and CUDA graphs. The problem I ran into was due to this line: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/bc2c6edaf163b1a1330e37a6e34caf8c553e4755/torch/nn/parallel/distributed.py#L929.

Looks like this operation is not supported during stream capture. At this point I'm not sure whether CUDA graphs support DDP training. Couldn't find any official documentation regarding this as well.

Comment: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/is-cuda-graph-compatible-with-distributeddataparallel/161261 According to this you need to do 11 warmup iterations, which you are doing, so I guess your problem is not the same as mine.

Comment: But please try the other suggestions in the answer. The doc has a list of steps that are required for DDP + cuda graphs.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation ([link](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/notes/cuda.html#usage-with-distributeddataparallel)), it is recommended to initialize the DDP model before performing full-backward capture. Therefore, the model can be created prior to the warmup step. For instance:

```py
s = torch.cuda.Stream()
s.wait_stream(torch.cuda.current_stream())
with torch.cuda.stream(s):
    ddp_model = torch.nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel(model)
torch.cuda.current_stream().wait_stream(s)
```